# HTML5 - svg rect Background

Tags: html, svg, background, rect

I am trying to fix a background-image for a rectangle svg. Is this possible? The code below does not work. I want to use a svg rect specifically because I can get rounded corners this way, with `rx="10" ry="10"`

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="50" height="50"
    style="background-image:url(image.png)"/>
</svg>
```